# Microservices - Does HTML belong inside API Gateways?

Tags: html, microservices, soa, api-gateway

When designing microservices with the API Gateway pattern, do HTML templates belong inside the API Gateway service, or as a standalone service?

For example, if some website (like Stack Overflow) wants to change their features at will (question layout, messaging, search, etc...), then they can inject features into their HTML templates.

If the templates are coupled with the Gateway:

- Latency is decreased
- Any changes to the templates affects the entire Gateway service.

If the templates exist as their own Templating Service:

- Latency increases
- Updating templates doesn't necessitate editing the Gateway.

I'm wondering which method is preferable for designing a web application using the API Gateway pattern.  What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the technology you use, but still I'd rather say no.

Assuming that the HTML part is your frontend, you want to deliver the frontend either per microservice (meaning one frontend per microservice) or as a own microservice.

But it's hard to say anything absolute - it always depends on the application you're building.

Comment: "No" to which one?

Comment: To pack it with the gateway. I guess you could do that with a single-page-application, but then you're using a monolithic frontend with a microservice backend. Per definition, a miroservice should work independently - which means that it needs a own frontend. At least if you're doing it by the book.